# Prove that the problem of REGEX producing strings with 111 as substring is decidable

Tags: turing-machines, computability, regular-expressions, decidability

I have been given the following problem and was wondering if my solution is correct (taken from the textbook exercise in the book Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Martin Sipser):

Given `{<R> | R is a REGEX that generates strings with 111 as substring}` shows that it is **decidable**.

My solution at the moment is:

```
   1. Build a DFA M such that L(M) = L(R)
   2. Build a DFA N such that L(N) = L(M) /\ L(R) (intersected)
   3. Run EDFA on <N> (EDFA = {<N> | D is DFA such as L(D) = 0(empty set)} is decidable.)
   4. Invert its output and return
```

Is that a valid solution? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $L(M)=L(R)$ by definition? What's the point of defining $L(N) = L(M) \cap L(R)$? Also you defined `EDFA` as a language. What does it mean to "run" a language?

Comment: One way to prove something is decidable is to write a computer program (maybe in pseudocode) that decides it.

Comment: Like Steven, I don't understand your step 2, or 3.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.